# Car ownership in GTAV story mode?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In story mode obviously my characters have their personal vehicles. But I also steal vehicles often. Because GTA? And abandoning them when I’m tired of them. And sometimes I get a message that some or other vehicle has been impounded.

I thought, to keep random cars, I should park them in a garage, at one of the characters houses or one of the purchased garages (this seems a new story mode feature?) but these random vehicles keep being impounded. And overwriting whatever previously impounded vehicles were there as I don’t care to retrieve any of them.

But I do want to buy/ steal a race car for Franklin to win races with and pay to upgrade it. And I don’t want it to despawn or be overwritten if I accidentally don’t park it in a garage and leave it on the street and it gets impounded.

So I’d like to understand why cars I don’t care to own are becoming eligible to be impounded when I simply hijack and abandon without visiting a garage or visiting LS customs.

And also, where and what is a fast car with good handling that’s good for Franklin to take racing and worth spending upgrades on. And If I do ‘use’ this car by accident I.e in a mission and lose it on the map:
I presume that if I blow up a ‘owned’ rather than personal car it will be destroyed. Other than total destruction how many other actions can accidentally destroy a car?
Is there any way to safely park cars on the street or will they always be impounded?
As above, is there some way to ensure stolen cars don’t get tagged as owned and impounded when abandoned? As i’d Like to have the safety net of being able to find car’s I’d spent money on in impound.

Comment: You should be able to call the impound lot on your phone to retrieve other vehicles that may have been "Overwritten", so you do not lose a vehicle that you put work into.  You will just need to pay a small fee to retrieve it.